# Reputation bug in new users page

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, users-page, association-bonus

I noticed my reputation on the users page of the new fitness site was 115, but my reputation at the top of the page was 116.

I triggered a rep recalculation which kept my rep at 116 on the top of the page and on my personal user page, however this caused my reputation on the users page under "week" to appear as 15. However on "all" it is now 116.

There seems to be an inconsistency somewhere, either everyone on the "week" page should not include the 100 merging bonus or they should all include the 100 merging bonus after the rep recalc.

Here is a picture:

[image: Image of Fitness users page, with xiaohouzi's entry having 15 reputation despite the 116 shown in the top bar]

Comment: yes, I am looking at a cleaner way for blanket ignoring the 100 rep bonus from the rep per week / month and so on

Comment: @waffles - Ok, so it's a work in progress. Understood.

Answer (score 1):

> There seems to be an inconsistency somewhere, either everyone on the "week" page should not include the 100 merging bonus or they should all include the 100 merging bonus after the rep recalc.

Fact: the exclusion of the merge bonus from the weekly/monthly/quarterly league/users-page has only just been implemented.  It used to consistently include it in all periods.

However, I think it works as is.  There must be at least one page that shows all users with full and final rep - so "All" seems to be appropriate.

Comment: No worries... I'll just wait here

Comment: That's all good and fine, but as it stands everyone on the "week" page except myself still includes the 100 merging bonus.

Comment: @xiaohouzi - I see now (I can't really - it's beta). The change is new, so a global recalc has to be triggered again for your site for everyone to be on equal footing. It will happen soon, but changes to /users is still being done so just wait a little while.